# Using async in ASP.Net-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I understand the concept of async / await. I have a question regarding how is used in an action context:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
{

}
```

> When is the action actually returning ?

If the async logic did not returned when execution reaches the end of the action function , is the thread just going to be freed and continue to wait for the async result ?

The action is not going to return anything until it gets whatever is waiting for, right ?

The "only" advantage is that the thread is freed until all the await calls are returned ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. (If the code inside the Login method actually does async work). So the thread is free to handle new incoming calls, etc. But the ActionResult is returned to the client after you are done awaiting whatever is inside the Login method.

Comment: So in this case when Login is called there is no "await" keyword ? Let's say I call it from an  Html.ActionLink

Comment: The MVC framework will 'await' your action in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the keyword `async` in a method to signal to the caller of this method that it contains some tasks which are run asynchronously.

> If the async logic did not returned when execution reaches the end of
>   the action function , is the thread just going to be freed and
>   continue to wait for the async result ?

Whenever you use `async`, you do add a keyword `await` to calls of some methods ( such as File IO, Database open close, a long runnning process etc).
So it will wait till that method completes & wont return from it.

> The "only" advantage is that the thread is freed until all the await
>   calls are returned ?

Yes. the framework will be able to do some other tasks on this thread while it is waiting for some action to complete.

Comment: But in the Login() example, you dont have any await keyword when the Login action is called , right ?

Comment: An async method with no await call will run synchronously just like an non-async method.

Comment: How can I call an async action with Html.ActionLink for example ? Is there an await keyword ?

Comment: @doremifasolasido In case of actions, you dont need to call it, the framework does it for you. In some situations such as when you are writing your own middlewares to be executed before your actions, the async you wrote above comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Async await is mostly used in GUI applications to prevent the GUI from hanging while waiting for a service call or long running operation. What async await does is that it gets a free thread from the threadpool and assigns the long running task to it, so that the main thread is not blocked.
In MVC the multithreading process is automatically handled by `IIS` itself. It can be used in ASP.NET MVC also for handling db calls or for calling a  long running web service though. So it doesn't guarantee make your page requests process/ page load faster.

As mentioned in [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

> In web applications that sees a large number of concurrent requests at
>   start-up or has a bursty load (where concurrency increases suddenly),
>   making these web service calls asynchronous will increase the
>   responsiveness of your application. An asynchronous request takes the
>   same amount of time to process as a synchronous request. For example,
>   if a request makes a web service call that requires two seconds to
>   complete, the request takes two seconds whether it is performed
>   synchronously or asynchronously. However, during an asynchronous call,
>   a thread is not blocked from responding to other requests while it
>   waits for the first request to complete. Therefore, asynchronous
>   requests prevent request queuing and thread pool growth when there are
>   many concurrent requests that invoke long-running operations.

Refer the article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the concept for asynchronous programming then there is no difference when using it in web or in other platforms.

Take a look at [Simple Async Await Example for Asynchronous Programming](https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/10/simple-async-await-example-for-asynchronous-programming/) by Stephen Haunts.

To make a long story short, it allows the running thread to do some work while waiting for the awaited task/s. If something is needed from a certain task then the running thread will wait for it before it can proceed. So instead of just waiting, your running thread is able to do *some* work.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
```

returns a task containing an `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 0):

> When is the action actually returning?

The action method returns when it `await`s an incomplete task. It returns an incomplete task to ASP.NET.

However, the result is not sent to the browser until the action method completes. ASP.NET knows to wait for it until the task returned from the action is completed.

> If the async logic did not returned when execution reaches the end of the action function , is the thread just going to be freed and continue to wait for the async result?

No, the thread is freed completely. There is no thread that is blocked waiting for the action to complete.

> The action is not going to return anything until it gets whatever is waiting for, right ?

The action method returns, but the request is not sent.

> The "only" advantage is that the thread is freed until all the await calls are returned ?

Yes. But that's a huge advantage. By freeing up threads, the server can handle a larger volume of requests *and* be able to respond to changes in load more quickly. I have an article on [async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) you may find helpful.